# creating a bitmap from 2d array using stream

Tags: bitmap, streaming

My problem is that I cannot understand how to create a stream from 2d byte array. I need to use the stream in order to create a bitmap(Stream). I have a 2d byte array and I'm trying to draw it into a bitmap.

```
//here is my array(I checked its size - 2000*2000 and values are byte 0~255)

    grey[i, j] = (byte)Imag2[(j * pervoe) + i];
```

then I try to create a stream and write my image into picturebox via Bitmap

```
        MemoryStream yy = new MemoryStream(grey[width,height]);
        Bitmap photo = new Bitmap(yy);


        pictureBox1.Image = photo;
```

I get a error - Index out of range exception - what do I do?

Comment: just answered below. thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

To be honest to me its pretty confusing question but i would try to anwser from wat i understand :-

Your input array[0][2],array[1][2],array[2][2].....array[10][2].

I would do like this :-

1. try to use FileOutputStream with append=true or
2. u can create arraylist and collect all bytes in arraylist and then
   combine them run the bitmap drawing function ( expensive i know but first ur aim is to get
   it working )

Comment: I have a array of numbers which vary from 0 to 255(the array size is the size of picture I want to display like 2000*2000) and Im trying to display that using bitmap class. I tried to use bitmap.SetPixel method looping through each pixel but it takes too long.

Comment: grey[i, j] = (byte)Imag2[(j * pervoe) + i];  //here is my array(I checked its size - 2000*2000 and values are byte 0~255)